# C: Append string by int

Tags: c, string, append

I'm trying to take a string, and follow it by and int. Here is my code right now

```
int myint = 7;
string mystring = "string" + myint;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `string` type in c, the definition of a c string is

- A sequence of bytes terminated with a `'\0'` or `nul` byte.

You can use `snprintf()` this way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  myint       = 7;
char string[100] = "string";

snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%d", myint);
```

this will not always work, but it will work for your current example.

You cannot use this with a pointer if you don't allocate memory and point to it with the pointer, that can be achieved this way

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int   myint;
char *string;

myint  = 7;
string = malloc(100);

snprintf(string, 100, "mystring%d", myint);
/* when you are done using 'string', then */
free(string);
```

Comment: Ok, just that I should mention that I was gonna say thanks until the sass hit. The only reason I pasted what I had was so that there was an example  in case the question was unclear, and thought it would be irrelevant if i posted what I wanted Objective-C as an example. Mkay?

Comment: I'm just saying that the answer could have gone without the "It seems that you have no clue how strings work  in c", being my bogus example that you pointed out was simply there just in case what I was asking was unclear

Comment: @TheCommonGiraffe that was rude, you are absolutely right, I just thought you was comming from a javascript background for the code you posted, so i deleted that part... sorry. You see, if you come from a javascript background you would have a lot of trouble understanding c strings. I removed the offensive part and again I am very sorry.